# Create JSON with Keys from Powershell Array

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0

I have this Powershell Array object with string values in it

`[value1,value2,value3,value4,..etc]`

I would like to convert it into a JSON object with a key called `value` that has the values in the array and makes it look like this

```
[
   { "value" : "value1" },
   { "value" : "value2" },
   { "value" : "value3" },
   { "value" : "value4" },
         ...
]
```

Is that possible in powershell? Keep in mind the array could be a length of 50 so it has to loop through the array 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in PowerShell v3+:

```
# Starting Array $arr that you create
$arr = 'value1','value2','value3'

# Create an array of objects with property named value and value of each array value
# Feed created objects into the JSON converter
$arr | Foreach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{value = $_}
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

You can do the following in PowerShell v2:

```
$json = New-Object -Type 'System.Text.Stringbuilder'
$null = $json.Append("[")
$arr | foreach-Object {
    $line = "    {{ ""value"" : ""{0}"" }}," -f $_
    $null = $json.Append("`r`n$line")
}
$null = $json.Remove($json.Length-1,1)
$null = $json.Append("`r`n]")
$json.ToString()
```

Comment: I assume the down vote was because the poster wants a PowerShell v2 solution. There is probably an elegant json serializing solution. I could not easily find anything that didn't make assumptions about the installed .NET version or didn't require some external library.

Comment: I assume that the downvote was because the poster didn't post any sample code. What the poster wants is possible in PS2.0, I've written my own custom JSON encoders in the past for some PS2.0 machines. Hoewever, since PS2.0 has been deprecated since 2017 (and since Server 2008) is out of support I would advise against using it. There are more then enough alternatives nowadays (proxy a PS session from a PS3+ machine, roll out a VM for your scripts, use a docker container) so there is no reason to keep using PSv2

Comment: @bluuf I was referring to why I was downvoted. I consequently added a v2 solution after being downvoted. It works just fine in this simplistic case, but is not scalable for other scenarios. I do agree with everything you said though.